# Make minimal working example for org-ref (Version 3)?

Tags: org-mode, org-ref

My .emacs includes these lines:

```
  (package-initialize)
  (require 'org-ref)
```

I have a file called orgcite.bib which includes:

```
@article{OrgCitations,
         author={org, mode and Syntax, Citation and List, Mailing and Effort, Time},
         journal={Journal of Plain Text Formats},
         title={Elegant Citations with Org-Mode},
         year={2021},
         month={7},
         volume={42},
         number={1},
         pages={2-3}}
```

My simple org-mode file is as follows:

```
#+title: simple test

citep:OrgCitations

bibliography:orgcite.bib
```

`C-c C-e h o` (export to html) generates a file that does not expand the references. Output file includes these lines (just the bold parts):

**simple test** --> This is the title so ok

**OrgCitations** --> This appears to be hyperlinked to nothing

**orgcite.bib** --> This is hyperlinked to orgcite.bib

What am I doing wrong? I've also tried with `citep:&OrgCitations` which does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Org-ref is a new export backend: it introduces its own menu, which you get to using the `C-c C-e r` prefix, so exporting to HTML is `C-c C-e r h`.

You should have a menu with an `[r]` section that is generated by the following code in `org-ref-export.el`:

```el
(org-export-define-derived-backend 'org-ref 'org
  :menu-entry
  '(?r "Org-ref export"
       ((?a "to Ascii" org-ref-export-to-ascii)
        (?h "to html" org-ref-export-to-html)
        (?l "to LaTeX" org-ref-export-to-latex)
        (?p "to PDF" org-ref-export-to-pdf)
        (?o "to ODT" org-ref-export-to-odt)
        (?O "to Org buffer" org-ref-export-as-org)
        (?e "to email" org-ref-export-to-message)
        (?w "to docx" org-ref-export-to-docx))))
```